# Facebook user ID Issue

Tags: facebook, profile, userid, info

I have facebook user ID's 
using this id's am accessing profile page of that particular user id.

link will be look like https://www.facebook.com/100001533612613
this link not working now.

```
https://facebook.com/zuck
https://www.facebook.com/100001533612613 (**not working**)
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001533612613 (**not working**)
https://m.facebook.com/ChrisHughes
```

how can i see profile using UserId

Comment: Plse refer :- https://medium.com/@shrawan25.sharma/urgent-facebook-sdk-app-update-to-retain-permission-access-a256b76e5bd5

Comment: there is no issue found in question the link is working fine.but you have to be logged in

Answer (score 2):

> how can i access profile using UserId

You can’t, because you are not supposed to any more …

You will now need to ask for the `user_link` permission first, and then you can request a (temporary) link to their profile via the `link` field.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#login

Comment: that's fine we con't access, that like  for showing at lest his/her profile page(if public)

Comment: before 1 month back that link will working fine, but not now.

Comment: Again: Not _supposed_ to work any more. You need to ask for the additional permission, if you still want to be able to link to user profiles.

Comment: here https://findmyfbid.in/ you can fine 3 links below **What's my faceboook profile URL?** first and last working fine. but not second.

Comment: I don’t understand what the purpose of this discussion is supposed to be now. There is only one allowed way for you now to get a link to the user profile, and which one that is, I just explained.

Comment: findmyfbid is scraping the profile, which is not allowed. don´t do that.

Comment: Plse refer below blog :- https://medium.com/@shrawan25.sharma/urgent-facebook-sdk-app-update-to-retain-permission-access-a256b76e5bd5